# Regarding the use of tradmarked public domain characters in a movie parody/satire

Tags: screenwriting, trademark

Ahhh Tarzan.

I was reading an older thread about public domain characters that had been lying in state for many years - but there was a sentence in the conversation that kind of applies to something I was thinking of writing.

I was reading about Beetlejuice 2 (I am not thinking of using Beetlejuice - lol) and one of the writers was involved in that 'Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter' film and I got to thinking of mash-ups.

If a film is a clear parody - can you use Tarzan as a character? (Tarzan is why I am here) Would a parody film - like 'Tarzan vs King Kong in Detroit' be something that would roust the protectors/moneylenders of Tarzan & King Kong's trademarks into action?

Or could a film - with the proper script - be made with little interference?

Is there some protection accorded by being silly/satirical/inane?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding copyright, parody can provide a valid defense, but not trademark infringement. Parody isn't explicitly described as part of fair use for trademark infringement. The rules are much narrower.  The notion of fair use in trademarks requires the use to not create confusion between products/services or imply an affiliation.

In the case of a Tarzan parody, you'd be trading on the fact that there'd be confusion -- that your Tarzan was the trademarked Tarzan.